# Android - Horizontally tiled hexagons

Tags: android, layout, tile

I am trying to create a horizontal scrollable view which is populated by hexagon tiles.
As far as I know, there aren't any prefabs for this in Android, so I would have to create the custom views myself, unless there is a better way.

These hexagons should be able to contain a view which consists of a button, text, image (hexagon itself is an image)

So I am wondering which layout type or method should I proceed with in order to reach my goal?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Gallery](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Gallery.html) for horizontal scrolling. As for Hexagon I fear you would have to make your own custom View.